# How can I create a new file for each n line occurance

Tags: python, list, dataframe, readline

I have a data like this:

```
ID 1
x y
3 4
4 3
6 8
ID 2
x y
3 4
4 3
6 8
.
.
.
ID 100
x y
2 40
41 32
6 8
```

I want to create a data file for each ID like ID_1.txt, ID_2.txt...
My code is :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
###############################################

fichier = "data.txt"
file = open(fichier).read().split('\n')
n =0
j=0
id=[]
for i in file :
    # print("********",i)
    current_id = j+1
    if 'ID' in i:
        id.append(n+1)
        print('n=',n)
        globals()[f'ID_{n}']=[]
        n+=1

    while current_id == id[-1] :
        
        if i.find('ID'):
            print(i.find('ID'))
            eval()[f'ID_{n}'].append(i)
```

I'm still getting an ampty ID_{n} list, any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but you are making it too complicated.  Open the file for reading and iterate through the lines, check for `'ID'` in the line to open a new file for writing.

```
from io import StringIO

# just make a generic file-like object to start with
writer = StringIO()

with open('data.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        if line.startswith('ID'):
            writer.close()
            filename = line.strip().replace(' ', '_') + '.txt'
            writer = open(filename, 'w')
        writer.write(line)
    writer.close()
```